# What is the best way to do many CRUDs in one view (without using ajax)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, design-patterns, crud

I have 3 forms in a view called 'home' each form submit different model, each form redirect to a create action in the respective controller. After create each controller redirect to the administration view which also index each model and provide edit and delete links.

I don't know if this approach is a good practice since i have to instance all in the administrators_controller, also i have to instance each model in their respective controllers again.

**administrators_controller.rb**

```
def home
    @user = Employee.new(role: :emp)
    @market = Market.find(params[:market_id])

    #INDEX EMPLOYEE:
    @employees = @market.users.where(role: :emp)

    #INDEX SERVERS:
    @server = Server.new(market_id: @market.id)
    @servers = @market.servers

    #INDEX TRAMITES:
    @task = Task.new(market_id: @market.id)
    @tasks = @market.tasks
 end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attribute(:email, params[:user][:email])
      flash[:success] = "User updated"
      redirect_to market_admin_path(current_user.market_id)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

**home.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:button_text, 'create') %>
<%= render 'users/form', url: market_employees_path %>

<h1> Empleados: </h1>
<% @employees.each do |employee| %>
  <ul>
    <li><%= employee.email%> <%= link_to 'edit', edit_user_path(employee) %></li>
  </ul>
<% end %>

<br>

<h1> Servers: </h1>
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Descripcion</th>
  </tr>
 <%= render 'servers/form', url: market_servers_path %>

  <% @servers.each do |serv| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= serv.id%></td>
      <td><%= serv.description%>  <%= link_to 'edit', edit_server_path(serv) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
<h1> Tramites: </h1>

<%= render 'tasks/form', url: market_tasks_path %>


<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Descripcion</th>
    <th>Duracion</th>
  </tr>

  <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= task.id%></td>
      <td><%= task.name%></td>
      <td><%= task.duration%> <%= link_to 'edit', edit_task_path(task) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>

</table>
```

**users/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: local_assigns[:url]) do |f| %>

  <%= render 'shared/flash_type', type: 'employee'%>

  <%= f.hidden_field :role %>

  <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.submit yield(:button_text), class: "btn btn-primary" %>

<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :markets, only: [], shallow: true do
    resources :employees, only: [:create]
    resources :users, only: [:edit, :update]
    resources :tasks, only: [:create, :edit, :update]
    resources :servers, only: [:create, :edit, :update]
    get '/administration', :to => 'administrators#home', :as => :admin
end
```

It actually works but i would like to know if there is a better way to do this.

Note: 'employee' class was created to use form objects pattern

Comment: Yes, using AJAX you can do it, but it is bad practice to provide all CRUD in single view page

Comment: Mmm okay, but what if i want to provide an administration view where the admin can create some stuff?

Comment: Just keep button for different actions, all actions will be JS requests, call ajax for providing form and new object these forms will be appended inside any corner of your view, render partial by js.erb

Comment: Single view for many CRUD actions will be complex view. If possible try to change approach.

Comment: Thanks, since i've implemented all without using javascript i would like an approach that avoid js and ajax, just to don't lose all the work i've done yet.